# Is it possible to restore a backup of Exchange 2007 to an Exchange 2010 box?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2010, restore

We are in the middle of a system recovery process and have the option of either restoring Exchange 2007 to our server or install Exchange 2010 as a new version.

The question is: would we be able to restore the backup we made of the Exchange 2007 mailboxes to the new Exchange 2010 server? Would save us an upgrade later on.

Please let me know what you think.

Bye,

Bart.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Microsoft made some pretty significant changes to the structure of the database between 2007 and 2010 and they are not cross-compatible. Certainly if this were possible it would be a great upgrade strategy but instead you have to introduce 2010 servers into your 2007 environment and move the mailboxes to a new 2010 server. Microsoft did introduce database portability with Exchange 2007 which allows you to move a database to any Exchange server in the Exchange Org in recovery situations which is nice - in the past (2003 and earlier) you could only restore to a server of the exact same name. Good luck with the recovery.